# Restoring database and "Logical name"

Tags: sql-server, restore

I already search and read some of previous post like:

[Restore Database from Database with Different Name](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/144382/restore-database-from-database-with-different-name)

[SQL Server Changing logical name](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/123662/sql-server-changing-logical-name)

I know how to restore, and how to change logical name.

I have another question.

For example in SMS I use "Restore Database" as source I choose: `AdventureWorks2014` as destination I set `AdventureWorks2014_test`, and press button OK

Currently I have: `AdventureWorks2014` and `AdventureWorks2014_test`, but currently both have the same `Logical Name` I mean: `AdventureWorks2014_Data` and `AdventureWorks2014_Log`

Is the fact that for `AdventureWorks2014` and `AdventureWorks2014_test` logical names are the same, may lead to some problems?

Can anyone give some examples of problems?

Answer (score 2):

No problems except that it might not look that nice. You can for instance be confused if you do `SELECT FROM sys.master_files` and see two databases having the same logical names for one or more file. But, in the end, the logical name only have to be unique within the database.

I prefer to tidy up this after a restore using ALTER DATABASE, I want to have things neat. Unless it is a short-lived database, like some test.

Comment: How about sql queries especially with ADO ? Do they needs to simply use `AdventureWorks2014` and `AdventureWorks2014_test` and the `Logical names` will not affect SQL queries ?

Comment: Yes, the database name is relevant, not the logical (or physical) file names.